# Page refreshes on submit click with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, xhtml

I have a small commenting system that I have modified and try implement into the site. It's in 'ajax'. When the jQuery with HTML is embedded into the page the commenting system works fine - i.e. when the user clicks on a submit button the code returns 'false', stops the page from refreshing and submits data. BUT when I implemented the code within my site and placed it in a seperate .js file the code for some reason doesn't work properly. I mean - the page after the onclick refreshes. Why is that so ? The code is not changed at all - when on its own, it works but not in the index.php site when implemented. I tried to change input type to 'button' and call a function from onclick - the page doesn't refresh but also doesn't insert the input..I'm running out of ideas as to why it is that so. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".submit").click(function () {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var comment_area = $("#comment_area").val();
            var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&comment_area=' + comment_area;
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            var emailaddressVal = $("#email").val();
            if (name == '' || !emailReg.test(emailaddressVal) || comment == '') {
                alert('Please enter valid data and type in message'); return false;
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "comments.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $("#com_list").append(html);
                        $("#com_list").fadeIn("slow");
                        $("#flash").fadeOut('fast');

                    }
                });
            } return false;
        });
    });
//END
//COM LIST

//HTML / PHP
<div class="slider">
<form id="comment_form" name="comment_form" method="post" action="#"     
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="16"/>&nbsp;Name<br /><br/>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>&nbsp;Email&nbsp;(will not show)<br /><br/>
<textarea id="comment_area" name="comment_area" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br /><br/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit_comment" value="submit"/>&nbsp;&  
nbsp;comment or <a href="index.php" id="cancel"   
onmousedown="$('.slider').hide();$('#com_list').show();"><u>cancel</u></a>
</form>
</div>
```

//comments.php

```
 if($_POST) {
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $comment_area=$_POST['comment_area'];
//$lowercase = strtolower($email);
//$image = md5( $lowercase );
$insert = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO comments (name,email,comment,com_date)   
VALUES ('$name','$email','$comment_area',curdate())"); 

}
```

////////////////

Thanks for any suggestions..

Comment: are you sure you are including the file properly?

Comment: Hi. Yes - I'm absolutely positive. The .js file is included in index.php withing script tags. I also have only one form in index.php - and the code works but the problem is about the input type='submit' - when clicked it refreshes the page instead of returning false.

Comment: I also tried to implement the jQuery code within the head tag in index.php. The same thing - it refreshes the page..

Comment: you said in the question, that when it's included in a js file, that it refreshes the page, and even if you put it in a regular button it doesn't do anything,  but when the code is embedded in the page it works properly
to me, this screams that the jquery isn't running at all. b/c a submit button, with jquery handlers, will submit the form and refresh.  which is the behaviour your seeing.

Comment: put an alert right after : $(".submit").click(function () {
  and let us know if it fires.  or, if your using firefox, with firebug, put a console.log('hello');   there.  and see if it shows up in the console.

Comment: @patricia , it is definitely running. I'm not so advanced at jQuery yet but not so dumb to not spot it ;] It returns alerts etc. I also use animate() function that is working - so it must be live..

Comment: see my answer, you've got an error in your JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aha!

there is an error in your js:

in my console i'm getting "comment is not defined "

```
if(name=='' || !emailReg.test(emailaddressVal) || comment=='')
```

and earlier you have:

```
var comment_area = $("#comment_area").val(); //<--
```

change this to comment and it'll get past that at least.

EDIT: a little background.  when firefox hits an error, sometimes it'll swallow it, and just stop running any javascript after that error, so your return false and or prevent default code isn't fire, so it's still going to post the form and refresh the page.

Comment: @Patricia - you're wonderful...! Just can't believe I skipped such a small and obvious error. True, also corrected 'comment' issue in comments.php. Thank you so much guys and especially you Patricia.

Comment: my pleasure :) feel feel to up-vote and mark this as the answer :) so this question won't show up in the unanswered list!

glad i could help

Comment: P.S....I on the other hand try not to sit up to 5am at nights writing /or implementing the code...

Comment: @Patricia - you don't know how much I wish - but it doesn't allow me ? You need to have 15 point reputation - it says...this post is actually first of mine, maybe that's why..BUT I will remember..

Comment: P.S. this site's interface and usefulness is awesome by the way...meaning 'cool' of course.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
$(".submit").click(function () {
```

To this:

```
$("#comment_form").submit(function () {
```

The `submit` event gets triggered on the `<form>` element, not on the submit button.

Comment: I´m guessing that´s a typo and you mean `$("form#comment_form").submit(function () {`

Comment: $("form#comment_form").  no need for the form infront of the ID, that will actually be a slower selector then #comment_form.   id selectors are the fastest!

also: the form click is NOT  what he wants to attach the behaviour to, that would have some pretty strange results.

Comment: I edited the answer to incorporate the suggestions from comments above.

@jeroen Thanks, that was a typo. I was in too much of a hurry, I guess.
@patricia Thanks for the tip. You're right, the ID selector is faster.

Comment: @patricia , @jeroen, @shef .Guys - it works, I mean this bit: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comment_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // stop refresh
- the question now is: it doesn't insert / submit data when clicked..

Comment: @patricia I mean the whole point of the code is to submit the data to comments.php when clicked and return false so it could prevent the refresh. With shef's code it doesn't refresh, true, but also doesn't submit..insert data. I need to re-think it..

Comment: P.S. the biggest question is why this code works perfectly when implemented into a new index page and doesn't when inserted into my index.php page. The links to .js are fine, form is fine, etc.

Comment: might be something in the rest of your index page that is interfering with it.

is there a live page we can see, would be a lot easier to debug.

Comment: @Patricia Ok - yes - the blog is almost finished and is under temporary domain name. Here it is: http://www.thebeautyblog.highermodedesigns.com

Comment: @Patricia - I know it's ineteresting...I think I will have to scrap this code and start with a new one..

Comment: hmmmm, when i try to run that bit of code form the console i get a syntax error.  might be a stray ; or , or something.  i'll see what i can track down.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your damn code clean, so you can understand what you are cooking...
This will work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comment_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // stop refresh

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var comment_area = $("#comment_area").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment_area=' + comment_area+'&submit_comment=true';
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var emailaddressVal = $("#email").val();
        if(name=='' || !emailReg.test(emailaddressVal) || comment==''){
            alert('Please enter valid data and type in message');
        } else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "comments.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#com_list").append(html);
                    $("#com_list").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#flash").fadeOut('fast');
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('#cancel').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.slider').hide();
        $('#com_list').show();
    });
});
```

Here is some more clean code...

```
<div class="slider">
    <form id="comment_form" name="comment_form" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="16"/>&nbsp;Name<br /><br/>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>&nbsp;Email&nbsp;(will not show)<br /><br/>
        <textarea id="comment_area" name="comment_area" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br /><br/>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit_comment" value="submit"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;comment or <a href="index.php" id="cancel"><u>cancel</u></a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is some other clean and **SECURE** code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_comment'])){
    $name           =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email          =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $comment_area   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment_area']);
    //$lowercase    =   strtolower($email);
    //$image        =   md5( $lowercase );
    $query  =   'INSERT INTO comments (name,email,comment,com_date) '.
                "VALUES ('$name','$email','$comment_area',CURDATE())";
    $insert = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
?>
```

Comment: eh? no it won't  his form doesn't have the class .comment_form it's id and name are comment_form.

Comment: Guess what - it doesn't work...it still refreshes. Also, doesn't return popout window on false input..( but that is is easy to fix ). So ? Interesting isn't it ?

Comment: @Patricia: Right! A typo! Fixed! Thanks!

Comment: @Mr X: Try again. Updated the code to attach the submit event to `#comment_form`, instead of `.comment_form`.

Comment: P.S. interesting thing is that the code ( the first I posted in my question ) works perfectly - when on its own as a demo etc.

Comment: @Mr X: Check the updated code, should work now. Works like a charm [check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/rDzGS/).

Comment: @Shef , thank you BUT no...ok here it is where we must stop and focus on it. True, it doesn't refresh, validation works perfect BUT it doesn't submit anything to comments.php.... but it does submit when it refreshes - what should not be a case of ajax. So the code needs to submit without refresh. So why it doesn't when returning false...it's definitely something conflicting in my pages. IE 8, 9 / FF4 are the ones I'm using..by the way. Still I cannot spot anything what prevents the code from running. If you implement the code from my question - it will work spotless...

Comment: @Mr X: I updated my answer. Get again the JavaScript code, because I added this `+'&submit_comment=true'` to the `dataString`. On the cleaned PHP code I gave you, I was checking if `isset($_POST['submit_comment'])`, but you were not sending the `submit_comment` value on your data string. So, it was not inserting anything, because it was not "entering" the if statement.

Comment: @Shef Thank you for the update..The code works now after Patricia's error spotting but I will stick to it for the future reference as well. Regards.

Comment: Thanks Shef for the secure code - of course I'm always using secure code, the PHP mysqli escape commands are on a different file.